# Unity DI call an injected method

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am using C# 4.7.2 and PRISM 6 with Unity

I registered a InjectionMethod to call *MyMethod*:

```
private void RegisterMyClass()
{
    object[] parameters = new object[]
    {
       typeof(IMyInterface)
    };


    InjectionMember[] injectionMembers = new InjectionMember[]
    {                
        new InjectionMethod( "MyMethod", parameters )
    };

    container.RegisterType<IMyClass , MyClass>( new TransientLifetimeManager() , injectionMembers );
}
```

The target class looks like this:

```
public MyClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        MyMethod();
    }

    public void MyMethod( IMyInterface example )
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

How can I call *MyMethod* from *DoSomething* in a way that the DI works correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MyClass.MyMethod` is used to *initialize* `MyClass` with `IMyInterface`. This, however, leads to the [Temporal Coupling code smell](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/).

Although Method Injection by itself is not a bad practice, using it inside the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) to initialize a class, however, is. Instead, you should solely rely on **constructor injection** as method of building object graphs. In other words, change the class to the following:

```
public MyClass
{
    private readonly IMyInterface example;
    public MyClass(IMyInterface example)
    {
        this.example = example ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(example));
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        MyMethod();
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        // use this.example
    }
}
```

This simplifies your Composition Root, because it removes the need to specify in a complex and type-unsafe way that `MyMethod` must be called, and provides you with a much shorter feedback cycle in case dependencies are missing. Furthermore, it allows `DoSomething` to call `MyMethod`, because `IMyInterface` will be guaranteed to be available at that time.